# Получение текущего значения из текстового поля

Tags: javascript, css

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="'+answer+'"/>
```

Изначально в input выводится текст. Как получить новое значение value, если текст был изменен. 
`$('#text').attr('value');` - выводит изначальный текст

Comment: `$('#text').val()`

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  console.info('Значение было изменено: Новое значение' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: Почему нельзя просто использовать [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)?

Comment: @Something потому что у событий `input` и `change` разное поведение.